Why is there a difference between an operator and the corresponding member function?
Why is there a difference between the operator call and the corresponding member function call with Clang 17.0.1? Shouldn't they behave the same way?
#include <iostream>
    
struct A {
    void operator()(int) { std::cout << "A...\n"; }
};

struct B {
    void operator()(double) { std::cout << "B...\n"; }
};

template<typename... Ts> struct C : Ts... {};

int main() {
    C<A, B> c;
    c(1);
    c.operator()(1);
}

Compiler Explorer
The call
c(1);

works, but the call
c.operator()(1);

produces the error message
error: member 'operator()' found in multiple base classes of different types

The error message is clear. I was surprised that c(1) doesn't produce this error.

Clang bug? Both produce the same error in Clang 18. https://godbolt.org/z/hMojah673

Yes, looks like a Clang bug, that was fixed in Clang 18. I can reproduce it in all versions between 3.3 and 17.0. It works as expected with Clang 18 and all tested GCC versions.

Nevermind, I get it

GCC 11. c(1) doesn’t produce the error either. void operator()(int) gets called.

Strange. I've tried versions 4.8, 4.9, 5.1 and 13.2. I haven't tried all versions.

That is why it is important to test the program with latest compiler version.


The call c(1); works,

This seems to be a fixed clang 17.0.1 bug. Both calls are equivalent and produces the same error in the latest version of the clang etc.
